# Custom text wrapping algorithm in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, textblock, word-wrap

Is there any way to implement a custom text wrapping algorithm in a **TextBlock** element? I mean automatic wrapping depending on control size. Currently I use **TextWrapping** property, but it doesn't work as I expected.
For example I have this string:

```
pleasant /'plez(ə)nt/
```

Currently this text can be wrapped like:

```
pleasant /'plez
(ə)nt/
```

But I need something like this (wrap only on white spaces):

```
pleasant
/'plez(ə)nt/
```

As I understand current implementation wraps on punctuation symbols also, but this cause to unexpected behavior with complicated text like word transcription.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
string s = "pleasant /'plez(ə)nt/";
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

output should be:
pleasant
/'plez(ə)nt/

Comment: Yes, but this should be done automatically by the control (TextBlock), it should go to new line only if there is not enough space to draw all words. User also can change window size and size of the control will be changed too.

Comment: Probably it would help if you could edit your original question and add the comment you just gave here into it. As your question now is able to be interpreted in a few ways.  in case I thought this answer was what you meant.

Comment: For an HTML/CSS environment, one could split the text at the spaces and wrap each piece in `<span>` tags with the CSS `white-space` set to `nowrap`.